# Modifying Vista / Windows 7 explorer behavior

Tags: windows-vista

On the Windows Vista  taskbar, you can middle-click an icon to open a new instance of a program. In a Windows Vista explorer window address bar (the thing that shows the current file path as a bunch of clickable folders seperated by arrows,) you should be able to middle-click a folder and open a new window there. Is there anyway I could write code to modify Windows to do this?

Comment: How can this belong on superuser.com if the question is for code to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Not an easy way. You could look into writing an [`Explorer BHO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250436(VS.85).aspx) that subclasses the Windows Explorer window, in particular the address bar control.

**Update:** Should mention that while BHOs are always mentioned in the context of IE, they are also loaded by Windows Explorer, unless explicitly registered not to be.

**Disclaimer:** Do not write a BHO after consuming alchohol. Writing a BHO should not be done by pregnant women, small children under age of 18, and people with heart problems. Possible side effects include weight loss, weight gain, sleep deprivation, increased number of SO questions, depression, vomiting, nausea, can affect your work/life balance problem, and lead to severe problems with your life partner.